# Is it possible to access to a SetUpFixture outside the projet?

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unit-testing, nunit, nunit-3.0

I'm writing some unit tests for two layers of my project, in the first layer I've got a class library containing the domain specific logic, the second layer is the application one.

So my test structure looks like this:

- Project.App.Tests (Unit Test project)

  - TestClass1
  - ...
  - TestClassN
- Project.Domain.Tests (Unit Test project)

  - TestClass1
  - ...
  - TestClassN

I'm using NUnit 3 and its adapter for running the tests in visual studio 2015.

I need to initialize for both projects a LocalDb (for some not worth mentioning reasons). So I added a SetUpFixture that looks like this:

```cs
namespace Project
{
    [SetUpFixture]
    public class SetUpFixture
    {
        [OneTimeSetUp]
        public void Initialize() { ... }
    }
}
```

As I needed it for domain project originally, this file is in the Project.Domain.Tests project, so it is easy for tests under *Project.Domain.Tests* project to reach the **OneTimeSetUp** method, but the problem is for the *Project.App.Tests*, they never reach the **SetUpFixture** **OneTimeSetUp** method.

Am I missing any config? or is it just not supported in the way I implemented it?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can try a `SetupFixture` attribute here, per [GitHub](https://github.com/nunit/docs/wiki/SetUpFixture-Attribute)  _A `SetUpFixture` outside of any namespace provides SetUp and TearDown for the entire assembly._ It should work if `Project.Domain.Tests` and `Project.App.Tests` are located in one assembly

Comment: It seems like something to do with namespaces, rest looks good

Comment: I haven't pay that much of attention to the **assembly** part, I misunderstood and thought it was reference to namespaces. I think the issue I'm having has something to do with that, I'll try put them in the same assembly for figuring out.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The instructions for use of a `SetUpFixture` assume that everything is in one assembly. Assemblies are run one at a time and only reference one another if you have made a reference.

It is possible for one assembly to reference another, of course, but NUnit only searches the assemblies you tell it to run for the presence of attributes like `SetUpFixtureAttribute`.

If the code is simple, the easiest workaround would be to duplicate it in each assembly. If it's complex, then I suggest putting your initialization code in a common assembly that is referenced by both test assemblies. Then the two `SetUpFixture`s can be reduced to a single call.

A further concern is parallelism. If your two setup fixtures would interfere with one another, then make sure you don't tell VS to run the two processes in parallel.

Comment: The key was that NUnit looks for the SetUpFixtures within the assembly.